# why data is print double

Tags: php, laravel

[image]Here is my controller function
[image]

My controller function

```
<?php
    $array = array();
    foreach ($requests as $request) {
        $pivot_id = $request->pivot_id;
        $t = User::find($request->tutor_id);
        foreach ($t->subject as $tutorss) {
            $pivotRow = $tutorss->pivot->where('id', '=', $pivot_id)->get();
            foreach ($pivotRow as $row) {
                $multi = [
                    'start' => $row->start_from,
                    'finish' => $row->finish_by,
                    'rate' => $row->rate,
                ];
                array_push($array, $multi);
            }
        }
    }
    dd($array);
    return view('user.tutor.tutor-wallet', compact('pivotRow', 'total', 'results', 'subject', 'rate'));
```

Don't need reapting values

Comment: if you are expecting only 1 row into `$pivotRow`, why do you need `foreach` there?

Comment: how to remove repeating values in array

Comment: better consider how to avoid repetitive values. otherwise, you can check this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: Could you provide `dd($pivotRow)` here?

Comment: ok i add dd($pivotrow) pic in my question

Comment: please check it i add picture in my quesion

Comment: @GhulamHaiderFarooqi I have added a modification to your code for fixing the issue, You can also reffer my answer

Comment: what is `dd($requests)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array("start"=>"10:00AM","finish"=>"12:00PM","Rate"=>100),
    array("start"=>"10:00AM","finish"=>"12:00PM","Rate"=>100),
    array("start"=>"10:00AM","finish"=>"12:00PM","Rate"=>150),
);


//Serialize each value and gives a single diamentional array with serialized string value
$serialize = array_map("serialize", $data);

//Remove duplicate values
$uniqueSerialize = array_unique($serialize);

//Unserialize to bring back to original format (multidiamentional)
$data = array_map("unserialize", $uniqueSerialize);
print_r($data);
```

[Demo Link](https://3v4l.org/fkvD0)

Answer (score 0):

Use below array function
array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));